# Class member function pointer as a class member

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

```
// class
class MyClass
{
public:
void doIt() const
{
    cout << "It works!" << endl;
}

void(MyClass::*fPtr)() const;
};

// main

MyClass *t = new MyClass;

// store function address
t->fPtr = &MyClass::doIt;

(*(t->fPtr))(); // Whats wrong with this line?
```

How can i call the function stored in fPtr? when i try (*(t->fPtr))(); compiler gives 
those errors :

error C2171: '*' : illegal on operands of type 'void (__thiscall MyClass::* )(void) const

error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

Comment: `(t->*(t->fPtr))()` i think should work

Comment: @KoKuToru: That is wrong as well.

Comment: @KoKuToru: Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(*(t->fPtr))();` is wrong, thre right syntax is `((object)->*(ptrToMember))`

means

```
(t->*(t->fPtr))();
```

More background info here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html
(But better ignore these macros from that page..)

Answer (score 2):

There is no variable called `fPtr` in the scope of the `main()` function. You need to refer to the member variable using `->` operator and then dereference pointer-to-member using `->*`:

```
// main

MyClass *t = new MyClass;

// store function adress
t->fPtr = &MyClass::doIt;   

(t->*(t->fPtr))();
```

Alternatively you can create a local variable and assign the pointer-to-member to it:

```
// main

MyClass *t = new MyClass;

// store function adress
t->fPtr = &MyClass::doIt;

void (MyClass::*fp)() const = t->fPtr;
(t->*fp)();
```

The latter makes it clear why the strange-looking construct above is needed. You can also execute a method on an object different from the one whose member variable of pointer-to-member type you use:

```
MyClass *s = new MyClass;
MyClass *t = new MyClass;

s->fPtr = &MyClass::f;
t->fPtr = &MyClass::g;

(t->*(s->fPtr))(); // Call f() on object *t
(s->*(t->fPtr))(); // Call g() on object *s
```

The object on the left of `->` tells the compiler which object to read the pointer-to-member from while the object on the left of `->*` tells the compiler which object to call the member function on.